# How to plot multiple plots in matplotlib when I am using a function for each plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to plot a graph with a lot of features, so I wrote a function for this purpose. I now want to plot 4 plots (2,2) when each of the subplot is a function that returns plot (g as an instance of seaborn).
I call the function this way:

```
g = comm_relplot(b53_communication,means_53,meanPstd_53,meanMstd_53)
```

and I tried:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows = 2, figsize = (20,10))
axs[0,0] = comm_relplot(b53_communication,means_53,meanPstd_53,meanMstd_53)
```

but it's just plot it after the grid.

example for one function:

```
def control_relplot(control_data ,mean_c, meanPstd_c, meanMstd_c):
control = {'7':'Time spent with child',
           '23':'Water preference'}

control_data['dates'] = control_data['submitted_at'].astype(str)

corr = control_data[['int_value_0','question_id','dates']]
corr1 = corr.copy()
for q in set(corr['question_id'].values):
    for ind in corr.loc[corr['question_id'] == q].index:
        if meanMstd_c[q] < corr.loc[ind,'int_value_0'] < meanPstd_c[q]:
            corr1.loc[ind,'int_value_0'] = None
corr1 = corr1.dropna()


sns.set_style("white") 
g = sns.relplot(x="dates", y="int_value_0", row="question_id", kind="line", 
            data=control_data, color = 'royalblue', linewidth= 3,
            facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True})
g.fig.set_size_inches(20,15)
g.fig.suptitle('B. Control 54', x=0.5, y=1.03, fontsize = 40)
for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90, horizontalalignment='center',fontsize = 20)
    x = []
    for ticklabel in ax.get_xticklabels():
        d = datetime.strptime(ticklabel.get_text(),'%Y-%m-%d')
        d = d.strftime('%b-%d')
        x.append(d)
    ax.set_xticklabels(x)
    #ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize = 12)
q = 7
for ax in g.axes:
    data = corr1.loc[corr1['question_id'] == q]
    ax[0].plot(data['dates'], data['int_value_0'], 'sr')
    ax[0].axhline(mean_c[q], c = 'lightgray', linewidth = 1)
    ax[0].axhline(meanPstd_c[q], ls = '--', c = 'gray')
    ax[0].axhline(meanMstd_c[q], ls = '--', c = 'gray')
    #ax[0].text(selff_data['dates'].max(), mean_c[q], 'mean', fontsize = 20)
    if meanPstd_c[q] == meanMstd_c[q]:
        ax[0].text(control_data['dates'].max(), meanPstd_c[q], 'mean', fontsize = 30) 
    else:
        ax[0].text(control_data['dates'].max(), meanPstd_c[q], 'mean+std', fontsize = 30) 
        ax[0].text(control_data['dates'].max(), meanMstd_c[q], 'mean-std', fontsize = 30) 
    if meanPstd_c[q] < control_data.loc[control_data['question_id'] == q]['int_value_0'].max():
        ax[0].set_ylim(top = control_data.loc[control_data['question_id'] == q]['int_value_0'].max()+0.5)
    else:
        ax[0].set_ylim(top = meanPstd_c[q]+0.5)
    
    q = 23

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlabel(None)
    ax.set_ylabel('score', fontsize=35)
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=30)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=30)
    if ax.get_title():
        title_num = ax.get_title().split('= ')[1]
        ax.set_title(ax.get_title().replace(ax.get_title(),control[title_num]),
                     fontsize=35, pad = 0.8, fontweight="bold")
plt.tight_layout(pad=1.08, h_pad=2)    
return g '''
```

Comment: But a [relplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a figure-level plot that creates its own axes objects - you cannot squeeze multiple sub-axes into an axis object in matplotlib (which is used by seaborn).

Comment: I see. Do you have an idea how can I plot 2 by 2 plots using this code for each plot?

Comment: No. Maybe there is a way to map them to specific facets of a 4x4 FacetGrid but I am not sure. I have the feeling that you should describe your data structure and the desired plot layout, and people will suggest easier ways to achieve the desired plot. I see a lot of `g.axes` in your code, so it seems you don't actually use the advantages provided by seaborn.